# Is there any google workspace api that will give me list of applications i have installed on my domain and their license details as well?

Tags: api, google-workspace, google-api-nodejs-client

I am building a saas where I can see information about my google workspace domain such as users info, apps info and billing details as so on. I am struggling to find any documentation that will help me get a list of marketplace apps I have installed on my domain and license details if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

The Admin SDK currently only provides the ability to list OAuth tokens that users in the domain have authorized on their own.

List all apps for a user wherein it stated that the Admin SDK provides the ability to [list OAuth tokens](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/list) that users in the domain have authorized on their own. With this, you could get the complete list of apps installed and accessible to an user.